# Redoing a try after catch in Java

Tags: java, try-catch

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Questioner {   

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean condition;
int tempInt;
double tempDouble;

public Questioner()
{
    condition = true;
}

public String stringInput(String text)
{
    System.out.print(text);
    return scanner.nextLine();
}

public int intInput(String text)

{
    do
    {
        System.out.print(text);
        try
        {
            tempInt = scanner.nextInt();
            condition = false;
        }
        catch (java.util.InputMismatchException error)
        {
            System.out.println("Please use valid input.");
        }
    } while (condition == true);

    return tempInt;
}


public double doubleInput(String text)
{
    System.out.print(text);
    try
    {
        return scanner.nextDouble();
    }
    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException error)
    {
        System.out.println("Please use valid input.");
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Right now, it loops infinitely on the catch after one error. How can I make it go back to the try after a catch? boolean condition is declared properly, no compilation errors or anything. The rest of the code in the class is kind of a mess as I'm waiting for an answer about the re-trying.

Comment: how do you know it's looping on the catch? It should be going back to the try, put in a print there or use the debugger. Also, what makes you think trying again will change the results you get?

Comment: "`while (condition == true)`": why not call the flag `done`, invert its meaning and say `while (!done)`?

Comment: We need all of the code.  Where do you declare your condition variable?  What's it initialized to?  If condition is initialzed to true and scanner.nextInt() throws an exception without actually moving the "pointer", you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: Since the input is in the try, it will be a different input, hence a different result.

Answer (score 8):

The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for `java.util.Scanner` states

> When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method.

So you'll retrieve indefinitely using this method.  In the catch block you'll need to skip over the token.

Comment: Im sorry, that went a bit over my head. Can you give me an example?

Comment: It throws the exception, but doesn't advance the file pointer.  Let's say the file contents are "BANANA 123" and it's at the beginning of the stream (e.g. the file pointer is at B).  Obviously a banana isn't an integer so an exception will be thrown, but the next time around the file pointer will still be in the same place. After the exception you could do something like "scanner.next()" which will return the next string ("BANANA").  Now when you do scanner.nextInt() it'll return 123.

Answer (score 2):

As well as Jeff's answer, there's no indication that anything will ever set `condition` back to `true` after it's been set to false once. You *could* make it a local variable, or you could just return from the try block:

```
public int intInput(String text)    
{
    do
    {
        System.out.print(text);
        try
        {
            return scanner.nextInt();
        }
        catch (java.util.InputMismatchException error)
        {
            System.out.println("Please use valid input.");
            // Consume input here, appropriately...
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

Now the method doesn't affect any state other than the scanner, which is probably what you want - and (IMO) it's simpler as well.

Comment: Sorry about my question.  I think I understand now.