# How to properly use try-catch?

Tags: java, for-loop, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to process how to use try-catch. I understand it'll 'try' the main code, and if it doesn't work it'll catch it and execute something different. I want to also keep prompting the user to enter a proper value.

I keep getting the inputmismatch exception error, even if I set my catch to have that in its block.

To clarify: The try-catch is going to be there for when I ask the user for ints on how long they plan to stay, and what floor they'd like to be on. Therefore, the errors I'd like to handle involve non-integers and if they are out of bounds of the 'hotel'.

Here is my code:

```
public class Hotel{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      int choice = 0;
      String guestName = " ";
      int stayTime = 0;
      int floorPref = 0;

      System.out.println("Welcome to the Hotel California.");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


      Room[][] hotel = new Room[8][20];         


      for(int i = 0; i< hotel.length; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j<hotel[i].length;j++){
            hotel[i][j] = new Room(0,false,"none",0.00,0);

            int roomNum = ((i+1) * 100) + (j + 1);
            hotel[i][j].setRoom(roomNum);

            int roomCheck = hotel[i][j].getRoomNumber();

            if(roomCheck > 500){
               hotel[i][j].setPrice(350.00);   
            }

            else if(roomCheck < 500){
               hotel[i][j].setPrice(200.00);
            } 
         }
      }

       // Guest check-in interface.

      do{

         System.out.println("What business have you today?");
         System.out.println("1. Guest Registration");
         System.out.println("2. Guest Checkout");
         System.out.println("3. Show me occupied rooms");
         System.out.println("4. Exit");

         choice = sc.nextInt();

         if(choice == 1){  


            System.out.println("Tell us about yourself.");

            System.out.println("Please input your name:");

            guestName = sc.next();

            System.out.print("How long are you planning to stay?");

            try{
               stayTime = sc.nextInt();
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e){
               System.out.println("Please input a valid integer.");
               stayTime = sc.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.println("Great. What floor would you like to be on? Enter a number 1-8, 0 for no preference.");

            floorPref = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The following rooms are available based on your floor preference (floors 1-8, 0 for no preference: ");

         }    
         if(floorPref > 0){

            for(int i = 0; i < hotel[floorPref].length; i++){
               if(hotel[floorPref][(i)].getOccupation() == false){


                  System.out.print("Rooms " +  hotel[floorPref-1][i].getRoomNumber() + ", ");


               }
            }

            System.out.println("Are available today.");
         }


         else if(floorPref == 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < hotel.length; i++){
               for(int j = 0; j < hotel[i].length; j++){
                  System.out.print("Room " +  hotel[i][j].getRoomNumber() + ", ");

               }
            }

            System.out.println("Is available.");

         }


      }while(choice != 4);


   }
}
```

Comment: `public static void throws IOException main(String[] args)` check this sintaxis

Comment: i entered in the throws part thinking it would help. still crashed even w/o it.

Comment: where exactly do you get this error?

Comment: Line 70, and this is what comes up: How many days are you planning to stay?jon
Please input a valid integer.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at Hotel.main(Hotel.java:77)

Comment: Please show error message's you get . and try to use System.out.println statements so that you can trace out where you are getting exception

Answer (score 1):

The `try-catch` block you have right now is flawed, because once you get inside the `catch` block, all the user has to do is enter something that's not an integer to crash your whole program.

Instead, to get `stayTime` and all the other ints you pull from the `Scanner`, create a separate function that blocks until the user enters an int:

```
private static int parseIntFromScanner(Scanner sc) {
    while(true) {
        try {
            int toReturn = sc.nextInt();
            return toReturn;
        } catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
            //Continue back to the top of the loop, ask again for the integer
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put this at the top of your code

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
```

and in your `public static void throws IOException main` delete `throws IOException` so it only remains `public static void main`
hope it will works

Comment: Nothing wrong with throwing exceptions! I'd much rather have a program whose `main` method throws an exception, crashes, and tells me what went wrong, than one that attempts to catch and clean everything up without telling me.

Answer (score 0):

the following is small piece of code to divide.If user enters zero then it will go to catch and you can also enter number.
**Note**
the code will go catch only once.I have used depracated methods.This is just an example as per your requirement.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
        DataInputStream d=new DataInputStream(System.in);int x;
        try {
             x=Integer.parseInt(d.readLine());
            int z=8;
            System.out.println(z/x);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("can not divide by zero");
            x=Integer.parseInt(d.readLine());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as to why it's still failing: all of the calls to `nextInt()` can throw `InputMistmatchException`, not only the one put inside the try part of a try-catch block.  And that's what's happening now.

Another issue is calling `nextInt` a second time inside the `catch` block.  Exceptions thrown inside a catch block require their own handling, separate from the try-catch block to which they belong.  So, if `nextInt` inside the catch block throws an `InputMismatchException`, it will leave the try-catch block and work its way out from there.  In the case of the posted code, that means main will terminate on the exception.

A side point, as musical_coder pointed out, the code needs to loop with the validation.  Otherwise, it would end up without setting values if the second attempt to read a value fails.

BTW, see this: [Redoing a try after catch in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529113/redoing-a-try-after-catch-in-java?rq=1), for a tip on scanner use that will lead to more headaches.  In fact, it tells why the handling with the try-catch you have now will always end up terminating the program.  (it's a matter of how Scanner functions)